# Use GLib in CLion

Tags: c++, cmake, glib, clion, pkg-config

I trying to compile my test GLib project using CLion. So I added `#include "glib-2.0/glib.h"` in my cpp file and added `include_directories(/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib)` in my CMakeLists.txt. But got output in CLion:

> fatal error: glib/galloca.h: No such file or directory

So how I can correctly use GLib in my project in CLion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the skeleton I use for glib on my Mac (glib2 and pkgconfig installed via [MacPorts](http://macports.org/)):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(HelloGlib)

include(FindPkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(GLIB glib-2.0 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GLIB_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 2):

The include directory is supposed to be /usr/include/glib-2.0 not /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.  Or, more portably, `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! And how I can use pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 if I choose this option?

Comment: @user2656632: `find_package(PkgConfig)` and then `pkg_check_modules(GLIB2 glib-2.0)`. See [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPkgConfig.html) for more info.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for your support but I get this error `fatal error: glib/galloca.h: No such file or directory`. How can I resolve it?

Comment: @user2656632: See answer provided by acarlow.